# Internal load balancer : Connection refused

Tags: google-cloud-platform, internal-load-balancer, google-cloud-internal-load-balancer

I am trying to setup a internal load balancer on GCP cloud , and the problem is, when i try to access the same via another instance which falls under same VPC I am facing "Connection refused" error. Firewall rules has been checked as well as cross checked that load balancer and standalone instance which is trying to access are in same subnet.

Comment: your description is not clear can you update your issue more clearly, did you Create firewall rule that allows all traffic within the subnet? Did you Configure a [firewall rule to allow Internal Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/internal/setting-up-internal#configure-a-firewall-rule-to-allow-internal-load-balancing) ?

Answer (score 0):

Internal load balancers are [regional](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/internal/#deploying_internal_load_balancing_with_gcp_clients), i.e an instance in us-east cannot communicate with an internal load balancer in us-central, even within the same VPC.

You should make sure that your source VM's subnet is in the same region as your ILB's

As a potential workaround you could use [this](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/internal-load-balancing-haproxy)